# I am able to access data on my tabs page but not on my homepage in my app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have retrieved data on my loginpage using API. Now I want to access that data.
I am able to access the data on tabs page as tabspage is the page which gets open after the successful login. I am not able to access that data on other pages like homepage, profilepage etc.

Tell me some code or concept through which I can access my data from tabspage or loginpage to homepage.

On loginPage

```
var headers = new Headers();
    //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    let postParams ='&password='+ this.loginpass + '&phone=' + this.loginmob;
   // console.log(JSON.stringify(postParams));
    this.http.post("http://www.btedge.appexperts.net/Ionic_Webservices/login.php", JSON.stringify(postParams), options)
    .map(
      (res:Response) => { return console.log(this.users=res.json());})
      .subscribe(data => {
        if(this.users.success=="1")
          { 

              this.loadingCtrl.create({
                content: 'Login Successfully... ',
                duration: 4000,
                dismissOnPageChange: true
              }).present();
           //alert(this.users.user_id);
           this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage,{user_id: this.users.user_id,distributor_id: this.users.distributor_id,user_name:this.users.user_name,user_email:this.users.user_email,user_phoneno:this.users.user_phoneno,user_address:this.users.user_address,distributor_name:this.users.distributor_name,distributor_phoneno:this.users.distributor_phoneno,distributor_address:this.users.distributor_address,distributor_email:this.users.distributor_email});


          }
        else if(this.users.success=="2")
          {
            alert("Phone no or Password Incorrect");
            //this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
          }
        else if(this.users.success=="0")
          {
            alert("Required Fields Blank..");
            //this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
          }     
      },
    error=>{console.log(error)});
```

TabsPage- Here i am able to access the phone no coming from login page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from '../../app/app.module';
import { AlertController,LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ProfilePage } from '../profile/profile';
import { LoginPage } from '../Login/Login';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { MsgPage } from "../message/message";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
 users: any;
  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = MsgPage;
  tab3Root = AboutPage;
  tab4Root = ProfilePage;
  userphone: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private navParams : NavParams) {

    this.userphone=this.navParams.get('user_phoneno');
    console.log(this.userphone);
  }

}
```

HomePage- on this page I am not able to access the phone no. What should I do here?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from '../../app/app.module';
import { AlertController,LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ProfilePage } from '../profile/profile';
import { LoginPage } from '../Login/Login';
import { TabsPage } from "../tabs/tabs";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',

})
export class HomePage {
  userphone: String;
  useremail: String;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams : NavParams) {
    this.userphone=this.navParams.get('user_phoneno');
    console.log(this.userphone);


  }

}
```

Comment: Except answer given, if you want data available across app, maybe you want to look into events: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[rootParams]="userData"` in TabsPage html layout (for all `<ion-tab>` tag).

Set userData ={user_phoneno:this.navParams.get('user_phoneno')};

Finally, You can get navParams any page of TabsPage.

Comment: and what if i want to take multiple parameters to other pages of tabpage?

Your solution worked for one variable data. I have more variables i.e. phoneno, email, name, id, etc

Can you please tell me how can i get them

Comment: you can set parameter as object  => 
`var object ={user_phoneno:this.navParams.get('user_phoneno'),data:"value"};`
and you can get this.navParams.data; or `this.navParams.get("").propertyName`

Answer (score 0):

**Login:**

```
var headers = new Headers();
    //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    let postParams ='&password='+ this.loginpass + '&phone=' + this.loginmob;
   // console.log(JSON.stringify(postParams));
    this.http.post("http://www.btedge.appexperts.net/Ionic_Webservices/login.php", JSON.stringify(postParams), options)
    .map(
      (res:Response) => { return console.log(this.users=res.json());})
      .subscribe(data => {
        if(this.users.success=="1")
          { 

              this.loadingCtrl.create({
                content: 'Login Successfully... ',
                duration: 4000,
                dismissOnPageChange: true
              }).present();
           //alert(this.users.user_id);
   localStorage.setItem('userdata', this.users);
           this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);


          }
        else if(this.users.success=="2")
          {
            alert("Phone no or Password Incorrect");
            //this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
          }
        else if(this.users.success=="0")
          {
            alert("Required Fields Blank..");
            //this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
          }     
      },
    error=>{console.log(error)});
```

**Home page :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from '../../app/app.module';
import { AlertController,LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ProfilePage } from '../profile/profile';
import { LoginPage } from '../Login/Login';
import { TabsPage } from "../tabs/tabs";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',

})
export class HomePage {
  userphone: String;
  useremail: String;
  userData:any;
  constructor() {

    this.userData = localStorage.getItem('userdata');
    this.userphone=this.userData.user_phoneno;
    console.log(this.userphone);


  }

}
```

Comment: Although I am able to access the data. But the homePage gets open using this code. But I want to go to tabspage and after that if I go to any other page then data should be accessible.

Comment: @BellTesting : I have updated my answer and used localstorage for transferring the data.

Comment: Not working. Same thing is happening 
I am able to access data to tabspage but not on Homepage

Comment: @BellTesting : Have you got anything in the console.log(this.userphone); in Home component?

Comment: Ya...
undefined

Comment: Check in login controller that you are getting the users data and while getting the data using getItem of localstorage in home also print and check the same.